# PSTricks Clipping

Tags: pstricks, path-clipping

Consider the drawing:

[image: wanted]

How can I draw this using PSTricks? (The stripes are not of equal width, in case that is of any importance.)

I guess I have to use clipping somehow but I'm sure even how to get started properly. All I have is the following nonsense:

```
% lualatex test.tex

\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \def\radius{3}%
 \def\trop{0.2}%
 \def\subtrop{0.25}%
 \def\temp{0.35}%
 \def\polar{0.2}%
  \begin{pspicture}(-\radius,-\radius)(\radius,\radius)
    \psclip{
      \pscustom{
        \psarc(0,0){\radius}{0}{\fpeval{round(asind(\trop),9)}}
        \psline(\fpeval{-sqrt(\radius^2-(\trop*\radius)^2)},\fpeval{\trop*\radius})
               (\fpeval{ sqrt(\radius^2-(\trop*\radius)^2)},\fpeval{\trop*\radius})
        \psarc(0,0){\radius}{\fpeval{180-round(asind(\trop),9)}}{180}
        \psline(-\radius,0)(\radius,0)
      }
      \psframe*[fillcolor = red](-\radius,0)(\radius,\fpeval{\trop*\radius})
    }
    \endpsclip
    \rput(0,\fpeval{\trop/2*\radius}){Tropisk klimbælte}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thsi just gives a black stripe instead of a red one. `:-(`

P.S. Nevermind the text; the important thing is the horizontal, coloured stripes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of `\psclip` is this:

```
\psclip{<graphic>}
  <stuff>
\endpsclip
```

`<stuff>` is clipped based on `<graphic>`. So, one approach to drawing the globe you want is to use a `\psframe` (with no fill or line) as the `<graphic>` and then just draw a regular `\pscircle` in the colour you want. To ease the code, I created `\drawearth{<from>}{<to>}{<colour>}{<text>}` to draws the earth segment from a `<from>` to `<to>` portion of `\radius`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,multido}

\newcommand{\drawearth}[4]{%
  % #1 = from, #2 = to, #3 = colour, #4 = note
  \psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none,linewidth=0pt,fillstyle=none](-\radius,#1)(\radius,#2)}
    \pscircle[linestyle=none,linewidth=0pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#3](0,0){\radius}
  \endpsclip
  \rput(0,\fpeval{(#1+#2)/2}){#4}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \def\radius{3}%
  \def\trop{0.2}%
  \def\subtrop{0.25}%
  \def\temp{0.35}%
  \def\polar{0.2}%
  \begin{pspicture}(-\radius,-\radius)(\radius,\radius)
    \multido{\iA=1+1}{2}{%
      \drawearth{\fpeval{(1-\polar)*\radius}}{\radius}{blue}{Polar}
      \drawearth{\fpeval{(1-\polar-\temp)*\radius}}{\fpeval{(1-\polar)*\radius}}{green}{Temperate}
      \drawearth{\fpeval{\trop*\radius}}{\fpeval{(\trop+\subtrop)*\radius}}{yellow}{Sub-tropic}
      \drawearth{0}{\fpeval{\trop*\radius}}{red}{Tropic}
      \psset{unit=-1}% Reverse direction
    }
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Since the image is symmetrical, issuing `\psset{unit=-1}` halfway through allows duplication of the code to replicate the lower half of the globe.

Comment: Very nice! By the way, what is the point of `linewidth=0pt` if we already have `linestyle=none`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: [This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX1Gq.png) without it (using the default `linewidth`).

Comment: @Werner: I cannot see your effect without `linewidth=0pt`. Up-to-date TL2022